# using jmock in Scala with type parameterized function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jmock

I want to test a function that writes output from in RDD in Scala Spark.

Part of this test is mocking a map on an RDD, using jmock

```
val customerRdd = mockery.mock(classOf[RDD[Customer]], "rdd1")
val transformedRddToWrite = mockery.mock(classOf[RDD[TransformedCustomer]], "rdd2")

mockery.checking(new Expectations() {{
  // ...
  oneOf(customerRdd).map(
    `with`(Expectations.any(classOf[Customer => TransformedCustomer]))
  )
  will(Expectations.returnValue(transformedRddToWrite))
  // ...
}})
```

However, whenever I try to run this test, I get the following error:
`not all parameters were given explicit matchers: either all parameters must be specified by matchers or all must be specified by values, you cannot mix matchers and values`, despite the fact that I have specified matchers for all parameters to `.map`.

How do I fix this? Can jMock support matching on Scala functional arguments with implicit classtags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jMock I thought has been abandoned since 2012.  But if you like it, then more power to you. One of the issues is that `map` requires a `ClassTag[U]` according to the signature :

`def map[U: ClassTag](f: T => U): RDD[U]`  where U is the return type of your function.

I am going to heavily assume that if you were to make this work with a Java mocking framework, go under the assumption that `map`'s signature is `public <U> RDD<U> map(scala.Function1<T, U>, scala.reflect.ClassTag<U>);`

Hope that would work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Jmock will take a second argument list for the ClassTag. Here's what I did, which worked this time: 
`oneOf(customerRdd).map(
        with(Expectations.any(classOf[Customer => TransformedCustomer]))
      )(
        with(Expectations.anything())
      )
`